# How to replicate np.random result directly?

Tags: python, numpy, random, random-seed

```
import numpy as np
np.seed(1)
a=np.random.randint(10)
b=np.random.randint(10)
```

I know that after setting the random seed, every time I run this code, a and b will always be initialized to some fixed value, respectively.

My question is: In a new run, how can I directly generate b's value without generating a's value first?

In my mind, I need something like:

```
import numpy as np
np.seed(1)
a = np.random.randint(10)
# DO SOMETHING to get some situation-specific information, something like a new seed
```

So that in the new run, I can do like:

```
# DO SOMETHING to load or set that situation-specific information
b = np.random.randint(10)
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, use `numpy.random.get_state` and `set_state`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(10)
a
# 5

# Now get the current state
after_a = np.random.get_state()

b = np.random.randint(10)
b
# 8
```

---

```
# After some work...

np.random.set_state(after_a)

b = np.random.randint(10)
b
# 8
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can just run random function and do not need to set it for a.

first time

```
np.random.randint(10)
# DO SOMETHING to load or set that situation-specific information
b = np.random.randint(10)
```